# Python Dropbox Import Fail

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I'm trying to use the implementation of Dropbox in python but I can't get the import line to work.

```
import dropbox
```

gives me the following error.  I have tried using the installation included with Raspbian and installing from source (git).  Any ideas?

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in
> <module>   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dropbox/__init__.py", line 3,
> in <module>
>     from .dropbox import __version__, Dropbox, DropboxTeam, create_session   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 19,
> in <module>
>     from . import files, stone_serializers   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dropbox/files.py", line 8, in
> <module>
>     from . import stone_validators as bv   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dropbox/stone_validators.py",
> line 21, in <module>
>     from typing import Optional ImportError: No module named 'typing'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`dropbox` requires Python 3.5](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dropbox), as it requires the [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module, which wasn't introduced until 3.5. You're trying to use it with Python 3.4.